# Django debug toolbar says I have a query that is duplicate 1367 times

Tags: python, django, optimization, duplicates, django-queryset

I have a short view but with a complex query (the model that uses comes from a database MySQL view). The problem is that when this view executes, template loads too slow. The Django debug tool shows that a query is duplicated 1367 times, but the duplicated query has nothing to do with the complex database view query.

1. Is there any way to avoid duplicate query?
2. Is this delay because of the second query?

Below, is my template and view code. Sorry for not showing them too good, but it is my first post in StackOverflow.

```
def simbouloi_list(request, eklid):
    paramorder = request.GET.get('orderoption', '')

    try:
        paramorder = int(paramorder)
    except:
        paramorder = 6  # default ταξινόμηση

    selected_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.filter(eklid=eklid)
    # επιλογή όλων των εκλ. αναμετρήσεων με visible=1 και κάνω φθίνουσα ταξινόμηση  αν δεν δοθεί παράμετρος
    all_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.filter(visible=1).order_by('-eklid')

    #all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('surname', 'firstname', 'fathername')

    if paramorder==1 or paramorder==6:
        all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('surname', 'firstname','fathername')
    elif paramorder == 2:
        all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('sindiasmos', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername')
    elif paramorder == 3:
        all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('sindiasmos', 'toposeklogis', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername')
    elif paramorder == 4:
        all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by( 'toposeklogis','sindiasmos','surname', 'firstname','fathername')
    else:
        all_simbouloi = EklallsimbVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('toposeklogis', 'surname','firstname', 'fathername')


    context = {'all_ekloges': all_ekloges,
               'selected_ekloges': selected_ekloges,
               'all_simbouloi': all_simbouloi,
               }

    return render(request, 'Elections/simbouloi_list.html' , context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'Elections/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

<!-- καλούμε το base.html που προσθέτει το σταθερό Menu -->

 {% block content %}


     {% include 'Elections/messages.html' %}


     <div class="page-header">

            <h3 align="center">Υποψήφιοι Σύμβουλοι (Δημοτικοί & Τοπικοί)</h3>
     </div>

 <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                  <form method="get" name="simbouloi">

                     <select   name="orderoption"  onchange="simbouloi.submit()">
                     <option  value="6" {% if selected_order ==  4  %}selected{%endif%}>--------Επιλογή ταξινόμησης--------</option>
                         <option  value="1" {% if selected_order ==  1  %}selected{%endif%}>Κατά Επώνυμο</option>
                         <option  value="2" {% if selected_order ==  2  %}selected{%endif%}>Κατά Συνδυασμό/Επώνυμο</option>
                         <option  value="3" {% if selected_order ==  3  %}selected{%endif%}>Κατά Συνδυασμό/Περ. Εκλογής/Επώνυμο</option>
                         <option  value="4" {% if selected_order ==  3  %}selected{%endif%}>Κατά Περ. Εκλογής/Συνδυασμό/Επώνυμο</option>
                         <option  value="5" {% if selected_order ==  3  %}selected{%endif%}>Κατά Περ. Εκλογής/Επώνυμο</option>

                     </select>
                     <input type="text" class="heighttext" id="livesearch" placeholder="live search"></input>
                  </form>

        <div class="divmargin"> </div>

                    <table>

                        <tbody >

                        <tr class="noborder"> <td colspan="4"><a href="{% url 'simbouloi_add' selected_ekloges.0.eklid%}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Νέα καταχώριση</a></td></tr>

                        </tbody>
                   </table>

                    <div class="divmargin"> </div>

                   <table class="table styletd1 table-condensed table-striped  table-hover">

                        <tbody >
                        <tr>
                                <td class="thick">Επώνυμο</td>
                                <td class="thick">Όνομα</td>
                                <td class="thick">Όν. Πατρός</td>
                                <td class="thick">Περιοχή Εκλογής</td>
                                <td class="thick">Συνδυασμός</td>
                                <td class="thick">Ενέργειες</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% for p in all_simbouloi %}
                              <tr>
                                <td > {{ p.surname }} </td>
                                <td > {{ p.firstname }}</td>
                                <td > {{ p.fathername }} </td>
                                <td > {{ p.toposeklogis }} </td>
                                <td > {% if  p.sindiasmos is None %} {% else %} {{ p.sindiasmos  }} {% endif %}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'simbouloi_edit' selected_ekloges.0.eklid p.simbid%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'simbouloi_delete' selected_ekloges.0.eklid p.simbid%}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
                                </td>

                              </tr>
                          {% endfor %}

                        </tbody>
                   </table>

                    <br/>

                    <table>

                        <tbody >

                        <tr class="noborder"> <td colspan="4"><a href="{% url 'simbouloi_add' selected_ekloges.0.eklid%}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Νέα καταχώριση</a></td></tr>

                        </tbody>
                   </table>



        </div>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , a good start point for django querysets evaluation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/

```
def simbouloi_list(request, eklid):
 paramorder = 6  # default ταξινόμηση
 all_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.filter(visible=1).order_by('-eklid')
 if 'orderoption' in request.GET:
    paramorder = int(request.GET.get('orderoption'))

 selected_ekloges = all_ekloges.objects.prefetch_related('eklalallsimbwv_set').get(eklid=eklid) 
 all_simbouloi = selected_ekloges.eklalallsimbwv_set.all()

 if paramorder==1 or paramorder==6:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('surname', 'firstname','fathername') # dosen't hit the database
 elif paramorder == 2:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('sindiasmos', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername') # dosen't hit the database
 elif paramorder == 3:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('sindiasmos', 'toposeklogis', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername') # dosen't hit the database
elif paramorder == 4:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by( 'toposeklogis','sindiasmos','surname', 'firstname','fathername') # dosen't hit the database
else:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('toposeklogis', 'surname','firstname', 'fathername') # dosen't hit the database


context = {'all_ekloges': all_ekloges,
           'selected_ekloges': selected_ekloges,
           'all_simbouloi': all_simbouloi,
           }

return render(request, 'Elections/simbouloi_list.html' , context)
```

**Update**

Finally code below worked perfect!

selected_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.prefetch_related('eklallsimbvw_set').get(eklid=eklid)

```
all_simbouloi = selected_ekloges.eklallsimbvw_set.all().values_list('simbid', 'surname', 'firstname', 'fathername', 'toposeklogis', 'sindiasmos')

if paramorder==1 or paramorder==6:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('surname', 'firstname','fathername')
elif paramorder == 2:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('sindiasmos', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername')
elif paramorder == 3:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('sindiasmos', 'toposeklogis', 'surname', 'firstname','fathername')
elif paramorder == 4:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by( 'toposeklogis','sindiasmos','surname', 'firstname','fathername')
else:
    all_simbouloi = all_simbouloi.order_by('toposeklogis', 'surname','firstname', 'fathername')

context = {'all_ekloges': all_ekloges,
           'selected_ekloges': selected_ekloges.eklid,
           'all_simbouloi': all_simbouloi,
           }
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don' t think I can use commands below:

`selected_ekloges = all_ekloges.objects.prefetch_related('eklallsimbvw_set').get(eklid=eklid)
all_simbouloi = selected_ekloges.eklallsimbvw_set.all()`

because "eklallsimbvw" is a model that created by "inspect_db" command automatically and describes a Mysql VIEW and not a TABLE, so this model has no foreign keys related to "Eklogestbl" model (as I understand for "prefetch" command).

It also raises an error like "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'" for the first command.

This is my EklallsimbVw model:

```
class EklallsimbVw(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
eklid = models.IntegerField(db_column='eklID',db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
simbid = models.IntegerField(db_column='simbID',db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
surname = models.CharField(db_column='surname', max_length=100,db_index=True)
firstname = models.CharField(db_column='firstname', max_length=100,db_index=True)
fathername = models.CharField(db_column='fathername', max_length=100,db_index=True)
comments = models.CharField(db_column='comments', max_length=100)
toposeklogisid = models.IntegerField(db_column='toposEklogisID')  # Field name made lowercase.
toposeklogis = models.CharField(db_column='toposEklogis', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
eidoskoinotitas = models.IntegerField(db_column='eidosKoinotitas', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
sindid = models.IntegerField(db_column='sindID', blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
sindiasmos = models.CharField(db_column='sindiasmos', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)
```

This is "Eklogestbl" model:

```
class Eklogestbl(models.Model):
eklid = models.AutoField(db_column='eklID', primary_key=True, db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
descr = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
dateofelection = models.DateField(db_column='dateOfElection', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
dimos = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
sisid = models.ForeignKey('Sistima', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sisID', db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
edrid = models.ForeignKey(Edres, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='edrID', db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
visible=models.IntegerField(db_column='visible', default=1)
defaultelection=models.IntegerField(db_column='defaultElection', default=1)
```